# Split users in teams

Tags: java

I have a list with a random number of users, and a class Team.
Each team can hold maximum 9 users.
So, I want to split them in teams but I'm stuck.
I coded the thing if the users are < 9 but,
if the users are > 9  means that I have to create a new team and then set the other users inside the new team while looping the users.
I'm stuck because the constructor of the class Team must be with 2 users.

Main

```
private static List<Team> _teams = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    final List<User> allUsers = Arrays.asList(
                new User("Lily",1),
                new User("Kecia",2),
                new User("Tanika",3),
                new User("Julieta",4),
                new User("Alla",5),
                new User("Pennie",6),
                new User("Anna",7),
                new User("Mohammad",8),
                new User("John",9)
            );
    Collections.shuffle(allUsers);
    makeTeams(allUsers);
}
public static void makeTeams(List<User> users)
{
    if (users.size() > 9)
    {
        //here
    }
    else
    {
        User first = users.get(0);
        User sec = users.get(1);

        Team team = new Team(first,sec);

        first.setTeam(team);
        sec.setTeam(team);

        for (User user : users)
        {
            if (team.getUsers().contains(user))
                continue;

            team.add(user);
            user.setTeam(team);
        }
        _teams.add(team);
    }

    _teams.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

User

```
public class User {

private String _name;
private int _objId;
private Team _team;
public User(String name,int objId)
{
    _name = name;
    _objId = objId;
}

public String getName()
{
    return _name;
}
public int getObjId()
{
    return _objId;
}

public void setTeam(Team team)
{
    _team = team;
}
```

}

Team

```
public class Team {

private final List<User> _users = new ArrayList<>();

public Team(User first, User second) {
    _users.add(first);
    _users.add(second);
}

public void add(User mem) {
    _users.add(mem);
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("======== Team =========\n");
    _users.forEach(user -> sb.append(user.getName() + "\n"));
    sb.append("=======================\n");

    return sb.toString();
}

public List<User> getUsers ()
{
    return _users;
}
```

}

in the specific example the users are 9 and the output is

```
======== Team =========
Mohammad
John
Julieta
Kecia
Anna
Tanika
Alla
Lily
Pennie
=======================
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect this code to do instead?

Comment: I want to split for example 900 users in 100 different teams in one loop

Comment: I assume each team must have at least two players in it, since the constructor of a `Team` accepts two players? (Why didn't you call it `Player`, by the way?) Then you need to make sure that if the number of players doesn't fit into one team, it is assured enough players are left to create a new team.

Comment: OK. Why use a single loop? And/Or why making your life more complex than it should be by taking 2 users as arguments in the Team constructor, instead of a list of users, or no user at all? What should happen if you have, for example, 901 users?

Comment: @JBNizet Because a Team can named team if atleast have 2 objects inside . 
If the users are 901 then the last user will not have a team. (this wasn't my problem its just a check that I forgotten to put) , I have stuck in the thing of creating new teams in my loop. ( Do you thing 1 loop in this case is bad idea? and if yes how I should make it?)

Comment: This doesn't prevent you from having a constructor accepting a List<User> as argument, and checking the list has at least 2 elements in the constructor.

Comment: This is true, but instead of creating a team and .add users will be better to create a temp list , add the users inside , check the size of the list , make Team (list) ?

Comment: Yes, since you can't create an empty Team.

Comment: Solved @JBNizet . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With a simple loop i think you could solve it

```
int countDown=0;
for(User user : _users) {
if(countDown>=9){
countDown=0;
}
 if(countDown==0){
    //New team stuff
 }
 //Add the user to the new team.
 //...

//Update count down
countDown++;
}
```

**EDITED**

Just repleace the number of players with your list size. And then you will have to create N teams with `numberOfPlayerEachTeam` each of them.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int numberOfPlayers = 10;
    int maxNumberOfPlayerForTeam = 9;
    int minNumberOfPlayersForTeam = 2;
    int numberOfPlayerEachTeam = 0;

    for(int i =maxNumberOfPlayerForTeam; i >= minNumberOfPlayersForTeam && numberOfPlayerEachTeam <= 0 ; i--){
      int module = numberOfPlayers % i;
      if( module >= minNumberOfPlayersForTeam && module <=maxNumberOfPlayerForTeam ){
        numberOfPlayerEachTeam = i;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Number of players for each team: " + numberOfPlayerEachTeam);

  }
```

Comment: The problem is that you *might* end up with a single user left, unable to form a team (since a team needs at least two players).

Comment: I didn't check this condition, you are right.. I do edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to do some refactor on your "business logic" a little bit.

I think you do not need to have `Team` class and it makes your life a little bit easier.

Your `User` class looks fine but I suggest you to overwrite the `toString` method which will help you to display the result:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    // constructor
    public User(final String name, final Integer id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ":" + id;
    }

    // getter and setter methods
}
```

And this is the main application which split users between teams. The most important methods here is the `calculateTeams` which split users between teams:

```
public class AllocateTeams {
    private static final int MEMBERS_IN_TEAM = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = getUsers();
        //int numberOfTeams = getNumberOfTeams(users);
        List<List<User>> teams = calculateTeams(users, MEMBERS_IN_TEAM);

        System.out.println(String.format("Number of the individual players: %d", users.size()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Maximum players in a team: %d", MEMBERS_IN_TEAM));
        System.out.println(String.format("Number of the teams: %d", teams.size()));
        printTeams(teams);
    }

    private static void printTeams(final List<List<User>> teams) {
        int teamIndex = 0;
        for (List<User> team : teams) {
            teamIndex++;
            System.out.println(String.format("---------- team %d ----------", teamIndex));
            System.out.println(team);
        }
    }

    private static List<List<User>> calculateTeams(final List<User> users, final int memberInTeam) {
        List<List<User>> teams = new ArrayList<>();
        int teamNumber = getNumberOfTeams(users, memberInTeam);


        for (int teamIndex = 0; teamIndex < teamNumber; teamIndex++) {
            List<User> team = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int userIndexPerTeam = 0; userIndexPerTeam < memberInTeam; userIndexPerTeam++) {
                int userIndex = userIndexPerTeam + (teamIndex * memberInTeam);

                if (userIndex < users.size()) {
                    team.add(users.get(userIndex));
                }
            }

            teams.add(team);
        }

        return teams;
    }


    private static int getNumberOfTeams(final List<User> users, final int memberInTeam) {
        return (users.size() + memberInTeam - 1) / memberInTeam;
    }

    private static List<User> getUsers() {
        int id = 0;
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("Peter", id++));
        users.add(new User("Alfonso", id++));
        users.add(new User("Arthur", id++));
        users.add(new User("Ashley", id++));
        users.add(new User("Arnold", id++));
        users.add(new User("Andy", id++));
        users.add(new User("Augustus", id++));
        users.add(new User("Angelo", id++));
        users.add(new User("Alan", id++));
        users.add(new User("Albert", id++));
        users.add(new User("Nick", id++));
        users.add(new User("Nicolas", id++));
        users.add(new User("Norris", id++));
        users.add(new User("Fiona", id++));
        users.add(new User("Fidela", id++));
        users.add(new User("Fanny", id++));
        users.add(new User("Francesca", id++));
        users.add(new User("Paula", id++));
        users.add(new User("Eliza", id++));
        users.add(new User("Elizbeth", id++));
        users.add(new User("Ernestina", id++));
        users.add(new User("Sharda", id++));
        users.add(new User("Shara", id++));

        Collections.shuffle(users);
        return users;
    }
}
```

**This is the outcome:**

```
Number of the individual players: 23
Maximum players in a team: 9
Number of the teams: 3
---------- team 1 ----------
[Albert:9, Norris:12, Francesca:16, Paula:17, Ernestina:20, Alan:8, Fidela:14, Nicolas:11, Fanny:15]
---------- team 2 ----------
[Andy:5, Fiona:13, Peter:0, Shara:22, Arnold:4, Elizbeth:19, Eliza:18, Sharda:21, Augustus:6]
---------- team 3 ----------
[Arthur:2, Nick:10, Ashley:3, Angelo:7, Alfonso:1]
```

I hope that the code is clear any you can understand it.